# Circle and circle collision (with physics), but when lots of circles pile up things go wrong

Tags: python, pygame, physics, game-development

I'm trying to make an as realistic as possible ball physics simulator. Currently, I worked out all the collisions between balls, and it works really well when there are few balls. But once you create around and over 400-500 balls, things start to get weird: The balls at the bottom get squished around, overlapping with one another. And once you add even more balls, things get even crazier, the balls start to almost teleport around at the bottom.

Some screenshots:
With 100 balls:
[image: Balls piling up normally without glitching]
With over 600 balls:
[image: Balls teleporting and overlapping at the bottom]

Does anyone know what is happening and what is causing this? How can the code be improved to prevent it?

(For ease of testing, use scroll wheel to create lots of balls in quick succession)

Here is the code, it isn't too long:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import *
from math import *

WIDTH = 1200
HEIGHT = 800
FPS = 144
VEC = pygame.math.Vector2

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption("Bouncy balls with physics")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gravity = 3200
colors = range(50, 255, 10)
sizes = (15, 25)

absvec = lambda v: VEC(abs(v.x), abs(v.y))
inttup = lambda tup: tuple((int(tup[0]), int(tup[1])))

class Ball:
    instances = []
    regions = {}

    def __init__(self, pos):
        __class__.instances.append(self)
        self.pos = VEC(pos)
        self.region = inttup(self.pos // (sizes[1] * 2) + VEC(1, 1))
        if self.region in __class__.regions:
            __class__.regions[self.region].append(self)
        else:
            __class__.regions[self.region] = [self]
        self.vel = VEC(0, 0)
        self.radius = randint(*sizes)
        self.mass = self.radius ** 2 * pi
        self.color = (choice(colors), choice(colors), choice(colors))
        self.moving = True

    def update_position(self):
        self.vel.y += gravity * dt
        self.vel -= self.vel.normalize() * 160 * dt
        if -6 < self.vel.x < 6:
            self.vel.x = 0
        if -6 < self.vel.y < 6:
            self.vel.y = 0
        self.pos += self.vel * dt

        new_region = inttup(self.pos // (sizes[1] * 2) + VEC(1, 1))
        if self.region != new_region:
            if new_region in __class__.regions:
                __class__.regions[new_region].append(self)
            else:
                __class__.regions[new_region] = [self]
            __class__.regions[self.region].remove(self)
            self.region = new_region

    def update_pushout(self):
        self.collisions = []
        for x in range(self.region[0] - 1, self.region[0] + 2):
            for y in range(self.region[1] - 1, self.region[1] + 2):
                if (x, y) in __class__.regions:
                    for ball in __class__.regions[(x, y)]:
                        dist = self.pos.distance_to(ball.pos)
                        if dist < self.radius + ball.radius and ball != self:
                            self.collisions.append(ball)
                            overlap = -(dist - self.radius - ball.radius) * 0.5
                            self.pos += overlap * (self.pos - ball.pos).normalize()
                            ball.pos -= overlap * (self.pos - ball.pos).normalize()
    
    def update_collision(self):
        for ball in self.collisions:
            self.vel *= 0.85
            n = (ball.pos - self.pos).normalize()
            k = self.vel - ball.vel
            p = 2 * (n * k) / (self.mass + ball.mass)
            self.vel -= p * ball.mass * n
            ball.vel += p * self.mass * n

        if self.pos.x < self.radius:
            self.vel.x *= -0.8
            self.pos.x = self.radius
        elif self.pos.x > WIDTH - self.radius:
            self.vel.x *= -0.8
            self.pos.x = WIDTH - self.radius
        if self.pos.y < self.radius:
            self.vel.y *= -0.8
            self.pos.y = self.radius
        elif self.pos.y > HEIGHT - self.radius:
            if self.vel.y <= gravity * dt:
                self.vel.y = 0
            else:
                self.vel.y *= -0.8
            self.pos.y = HEIGHT - self.radius

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.pos, self.radius)

    def kill(self):
        __class__.instances.remove(self)
        __class__.regions[self.region].remove(self)
        del self

running = True
while running:
    dt = clock.tick_busy_loop(FPS) / 1000
    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Bouncy balls with physics | FPS: {str(int(clock.get_fps()))} | Ball count: {len(Ball.instances)}")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mpos = VEC(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            if sum([len(balls) for balls in Ball.regions.values()]) <= 1000:
                Ball(mpos)
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_c:
                for ball in Ball.instances.copy():
                    ball.kill()

    for ball in Ball.instances:
        ball.update_position()
        ball.update_pushout()
        ball.update_collision()
        ball.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

This is the code that gets performed when two balls collide:

```
self.vel *= 0.85
n = (ball.pos - self.pos).normalize()
k = self.vel - ball.vel
p = 2 * (n * k) / (self.mass + ball.mass)
self.vel -= p * ball.mass * n
ball.vel += p * self.mass * n
```

gotten from this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing, code-debugging, or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: This is all I've tried, because there is nothing else to try since this is the only method I can think of.

Comment: Which is why I'm asking for help, whether anyone knows a method that would prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

it is due to the gravity factor you added, this causes cercles to "go down" and squish the cercles under them when they should be in equilibrium

I can't test it right now but my guess would be to apply g to your k factor instead of the main velocity (I'm not 100% sure tho)

Tell me if it does

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm slightly confused on what you mean (maybe I'm dumb), but since I want the ball to fall normally as well, wouldn't they have to "fall" every frame instead of when and only when balls collide?

Comment: I only speat one minute on the big project, I would speat some more in 1 hour, basically your problem is that gravity is given to balls that have other balls under them, and so they "push" down, and the more layers of balls you have the more they push (like in real life)

Comment: Thank you, I think that is indeed the problem, I will try to find a solution to it.

Comment: It seems that as long as the FPS stays high, everything works fine with a lot of balls, as soon as fps starts to drop, the balls sink more and more into each other thus starting to get chaotic. If I limit the FPS to 60, it will start to get chaotic much sooner than normal. I'm wondering if it might be something to do with the way I'm calculating and using dt.

Comment: oh that's interesting to know, are the calculation of position and ftp linked in any way?